# VBA VLookup in Loop

Tags: vba, loops, vlookup

I´m trying to do a VLOOKUP of a column data set at a Sheet called "SyS" in G column. and I'd like to Vlookup relevant data using columns in another sheet called "CONF_mapping", located in the same Workbook. I need to find my data located at the range ("A1:E65000") (It's at column A, but I need to retrieve data from other columns with my vlookup to SyS). I'm not getting good results with my code, and I beg your pardon, it´s my first question in the forum.

```
Worksheets("SyS").Select
Dim wsThis As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range

Sheets("CONF_mapping").Columns(2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("SyS").Columns(8)
Set wsThis = Sheets("SyS")
    With wsThis
        For Each aCell In .Range("A1:E65000")
            '.Cells(aCell.Row, 8) = "Not Found"
            On Error Resume Next
            .Cells(aCell.Row, 8) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                            aCell.value, wsThat.Range("G2:G65000"), 2, False)
            On Error GoTo 0
         Next aCell
     End With
Worksheets("SyS").Select
```

I have find this code but I was not able to make it works for me.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You don't show the definition of `wsThat`.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What appears to be the problem?

Comment: Its just copy the column 2 of CONF_mapping in column 8 of SyS instead of doing the vlookup.. Im not able to do it work...

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake here:

```
VLookup(aCell.value, wsThat.Range("G2:G65000"), 2, False)
```

Range "G2:G65000" Have just 1 column G, but you try to get column#2 which does not exists.

UPD:
I guess you need something like this:

`Const COLUMN_TO_MATCH_IN_SYS = 8 
Const COLUMN_TO_MATCH_IN_CONF = 1
Sub test()
    Dim wsSys As Worksheet
    Dim wsConf As Worksheet
    Set wsSys = Sheets("SyS")
    Set wsConf = Sheets("CONF_mapping")
    Dim RowSys As Range
    Dim RowConf As Range
    For Each RowSys In wsSys.UsedRange.Rows
        For Each RowConf In wsConf.UsedRange.Rows
            If RowSys.Cells(1, COLUMN_TO_MATCH_IN_SYS) = _
               RowConf.Cells(1, COLUMN_TO_MATCH_IN_CONF) Then
                ' Copy row values which is needed
                RowSys.Cells(1, 6) = RowConf.Cells(1, 1) ' From column A(conf) to G(sys)
                RowSys.Cells(1, 7) = RowConf.Cells(1, 2) ' From column B(conf) to H (sys)
            End If
        Next aCell
    Next
End Sub`

With this solution you don't need to search the Range for each cell (just for each row), so it will work 5 times faster.

Comment: Hmm true... Thank you.. but it still doing what I want to do